# Cannot use Cell().copy to copy from one workbook to another?

Tags: copy, directory, cells

I am trying to write some vba code controlled by a command button to open all excel files in a folder and copy select data from each file into a master file.

I have the file search part down, which I thought would be the most difficult part. But For some reason the Cell().copy is not functioning correctly. (code below)

```
Private Sub Hot_Press_Update_Click()


'This file cannot be placed in the folder it is searching through
Dim wbk As Workbook
Dim Filename As String
Dim Path As String
Path = "C:\test\"
Filename = Dir(Path & "*.xls*")
thiswbk = ActiveWorkbook.Name
x = 0

    Do While Len(Filename) > 0
    Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(Path & Filename)

        Windows(wbk.Name).Activate
            wbk.Sheets(1).Select  '''''this works in source workbook
            Cells(54, 10).Copy   '''this copies from master workbook
                Windows(thiswbk).Activate ''everything else
                    Sheets(3).Select 'works perfectly
                        Cells(3 + x, 5).Select
                        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

        x = x + 1



    wbk.Close True
    Filename = Dir
Loop

End Sub
```

The copy is currently copying a cell from the master file instead of the source file, which the line before the before the code selects the sheet in the correct workbook.

I have asked a friend to try this code and it actually works for him.  The files I am pulling data out of have a short macro to fill a cell with the date. I am not sure if this has anything to do with it but it was the only difference between my sheets and my friends sheets.

Any input will be appreciated